# Detect and Distinguish Chrome tab been closed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I know there's a lot of javascript about beforeunload & unload to do the things like sent the confirmation then do the logout;

But, today my situation is when I do the redirect or refresh the page, I don't want to show the confirmation and do the logout;

So, problem is how to distinguish the user's action between close chrome tab and others, please let me know if I miss any thing I could do by javascript.

ps:my redirect not called by tag a hyperlink or submit form, so I don't wanna to use the onKeyPress or something like these hard code solution, thanks.

Comment: Can't you initialize a simple flag before initiating redirect or refresh And check the state of same flag in the unload function?

Comment: @CuriousMind thanks for sharing, you mean that like I detect the window location changed and set the flag to record it?